# How limit of byte datatype in java is -128 to 127?

Tags: java

I have a doubt that byte datatype has `1` byte memory which means `8` bits, in it and `1` bit is reserved as sign bit that leaves `7` bits for numeric values.

So `7` bits can have highest value

> 2<sup>6</sup>+2<sup>5</sup>+2<sup>4</sup>+2<sup>3</sup>+2<sup>2</sup>+2<sup>1</sup>+2<sup>0</sup> = 127

so how come the limit for byte datatype is `-128 to 127`?

Comment: See this: [Binary: Plusses & Minuses (Why We Use Two's Complement)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lKTsv6iVxV4) (YouTube video)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read about [2's complement notation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)
The 2’s representation is a variation on 1's complement which does not
have 2 representations for 0.
This makes the hardware that does arithmetic (addition, really) faster than
for the other representations.
**A 3-bit example**

```
bit pattern: 100 101 110 111 000 001 010 011
1's comp:     -3  -2  -1   0   0   1   2   3
2's comp:     -4  -3  -2  -1   0   1   2   3
```

The negative values are all ***slid*** down by one, **eliminating the extra
zero representation**.

Answer (score 4):

You have `8` bits, so `2`<sup>`8`</sup> = `256` possibilities. Between `-128` and `127` (inclusive), there are exactly `256` integer numbers.

In your calculation, you're counting `0` twice, once as `+0000000` and once as `-0000000`.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah you've answered your own question, if you can have 7 bits for numeric representation that means you can have **128** possible numbers. So **0-127** is a total of 128 values, but then you can use that other bit for 128 negative values. As 0 is already accounted for in the positive values (0-127), this allows for 128 negative values hence total range is -128 to +127.